# If an 'after' DDL trigger causes an error, is the DDL rolled back?

Tags: oracle, trigger, ddl, rollback

It [has been suggested](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:7072180788422#7084625440626) that DDL is logically performed something like this:

```
begin
    COMMIT;
    perform any appropriate pre-DDL trigger code;
    do the ddl;
    perform any appropriate post-DDL trigger code;
    COMMIT;
exception
    when others then
         ROLLBACK;
         raise;
end;
```

Which would suggest that any error in a trigger would cause the DDL to be rolled back. Is this the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer, at least on 11.2, is "It depends":

This `create` is rolled back:

```sql
create trigger trig_foo after create on schema
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Dont do it!');
end;
/
--
create table foo as select level as id from dual connect by level<=10000;
/*
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: Dont do it!
*/
--
select count(*) from foo;
/*
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
*/
```

But this `truncate` is not:

```sql
create table foo as select level as id from dual connect by level<=10000;
--
create trigger trig_foo after truncate on schema
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Dont do it!');
end;
/
--
truncate table foo;
/*
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: Dont do it!
*/
select count(*) from foo;
/*
COUNT(*)               
---------------------- 
0                  
*/
```